# How to only expose certain classes and methods?

Tags: java, api

I am tasked to create a reusable piece of software as a library/API. Right now I have every class as public in multiple packages and the methods within them are mostly private.

Since this is supposed to be an API, I wish to hide all the classes except for exposing a few classes and methods.

I can't use the private modifier for the classes as I refer to them in other packages within the project. I also do not want to inherit the classes unnecessarily in order to access the methods within.

What should I do to expose certain classes and methods while maintaining the ability to access them within my project?

Comment: Read about `default` or `protected` access controls. they may be what you need.

Comment: If the classes need each other it may make sense to place them in the same package and use the default modifier for the non-API methods or classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really suggest that you chart down the following on a piece of paper before you start designing your API.

**Pre Work**

1. Have you identified all the types of interacting entities. Each entity can be formed into an object.
2. At what layer (Controller/Facade/DAO etc ) you wish to use each of these.
3. Are any of the Objects expected to be transferred over a network.
4. What data will your entire API be exposing.

**Designing**
You would normally want to do the following:-
If your entities (in part 1) are related and may contain common info, create 1 entity ( Example `Common`)  to keep the common data (like timestamps of the request, device info etc) and make others that can contain this info, inherit this entity. ensure to have the properties of the common entity as protected. 
Common will look something like

```
   public class Common{
         protected _deviceId;
         protected _reqTimeStamp;
         protected _osVersion;

         //Getters and Setters. 
   }
```

For example, if you API is using the JSON request data received from Mobile Apps, you can have Common to contain the data given above in point 1. You can create another Object  as follows

```
public class UserInfo extends Common{
         private String _userName;
         private String _userMailId;

         //getters and setters 
}
```

Try to keep minimum entities for your Data Transfer between the layers. If the service layers that your API serves, are situated on different servers, then you may want to keep it Serializable and ensure that such DTOs do not contain chunks of huge information.

Similarly, when you segregate, the functionality of your API, try to see what functionalities are similar and commonly required. Move them to abstract classes and make the *implementations to the interfaces* that classify other behavior extend the abstract classes.

See this example below.

```
public abstract class CommonBehaviour {

protected String _commonId;

public void commonBehaviourOne()
{
    //Behaviour common to implementations
}

    abstract public void overrideThisBehaviour(); 

    //getters and setters
  }
```

So now if you have two types of behaviours in implementations that have a common functionality between them.

```
public interface Designable {

}

public class DesignerImpl extends CommonBehaviour implements Designable {

    @Override
    public void overrideThisBehaviour() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**The decision to make the classes public, private or default will be easy once you have the pre-requisites clear. You have to brainstorm, discuss amongst the stakeholders and brainstorm again. You will definitely come up with a good API**

**References for your help**

There is plenty of information available on the internet for people who enter designing.
As far as books are concerned, I referred, "[Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AA36RZY)" and [Design Patterns by Gamma](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) . Although i found Gamma more comprehensive, former is good for newbies.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it has made my understanding of designing an API much more clear. However, I see that the example codes uses protected, which prevents codes in other packages from accessing the methods within the classes. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You are right @AmultexHeart My bad! Edited the answer. For the behaviour to be accessible. It should be public

Answer (score 2):

On an API, you should only expose interfaces and business objects. Normally, these are on different maven artifacts than the implementation of the interfaces.

In short: Make a maven project for domain objects, another for API interfaces, and another for API implementation. Then distribute to your clients only the first two.

Concerning the dependencies: Implementation project should depend on both API and business objects projects. API project should depend only on business objects project. Business object project should depend on neither of both.

Comment: Unfortunately the project I'm working on uses Ant and not Maven. But I might need to know more about Maven for future projects. Does building a Maven project into a jar file include the dependencies as well? If that's the case, then my implementation classes would be exposed as well.

Comment: Maven does not include dependencies on a jar project (It does on war projects, but this it's not the case). I wrote Maven cause it's the most used, but the concept is the same if you use Ant.

Answer (score 1):

Make your classes as public, if you have methods to expose.
The method which is used locally in its class has to be private
The method which should to be exposed, takes public
The method which should to be visible inside your API, and not out, takes protected or default.

Comment: An other solution is tu use interface, but you should manage the instanciation yourself in order to put in an interface typed variable an instance of the implemented class

Comment: I am using an interface and have concrete classes that implement that interface. Is there any way to make the interface public but keep the classes private/protected, while maintaining the ability of the class to be called from other packages?

Comment: You can't, because the visiblity is inherited from super class. But, you can offer Factory or Builder in order to create instances.